# Если полоса прокрутки дошла до заданной точки, сделать что-то

Tags: jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке страницы, после того как пролистаешь путь равный высоте экрана сделать что то?

Надеюсь смог объясниться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
        // действия по достижении нужной точки
    } else {
        // действия по возврату
    }
});
```

Не забудьте подключить jQuery

Comment: благодарю!

Comment: @Кудрин Сергей а как сделать то же самое, только при прокрутке до определенного id заголовка?